# how to change the margin of the piechart in achartengine?

Tags: android, achartengine

I am Using achartengine api for drawing piechart. Defaultly the Piechart displays in the center but I want to move it to the left corner of the layout I used the 
"setMargin()" but it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are creating the `PieChart` instance yourself then you can set the `centerX` and `centerY` of the chart to change its location.

```
PieChart chart = new PieChart(dataset, renderer);
chart.setCenterX(someValue);
chart.setCenterY(someValue);
mChartView = new GraphicalView(context, chart);
```